# Solving differential equation $y''-y'^2/y+y'/x=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods

What approach we have to solve the following differential equation?

$$y''(x)- \frac{y'(x)^2}{y} + \frac{y'(x)}{x}=0$$

The known solution is $y(x) = c_2 * x^{c_1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle the same reduction as the other answer, but the other way around:

Substitute $u=\frac{y'}{y}=(\log|y|)'$ to find $u'=\frac1y(y''-\frac{y'^2}y)$ and consequently
$$
u'+\frac{u}x=0\iff (ux)'=0.
$$

Comment: Your answer makes sense and managed to do variable substitution in one go.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Let $y=e^z$ to make the equation $$\frac{e^{z} \left(x z''+z'\right)}{x}=0$$ This reduces to $$x z''+z'=0$$ Reduce the order $z'=t$ and continue.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer, let the $y=exp(z)$ is purely from experience or is there a trick? Your answer involves two step of variable replacement and it is quite neat.

Comment: @user424318. You are very welcome ! At my age, what is the part of experience ? I don't know; but when I saw the equation, it has been my first and last though ! This first transform happens is so many problems that you must  remember it. Is simplifies so many differentiatil equations !

Answer (score 1):

It dawned on me that the first couple terms look very close to a quotient rule.  It seems this equation falls apart when you divide both sides by $y$.

$$\frac{yy''-y'^2}{y^2}+\frac{y'}{xy}=0$$

$$\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'+\frac{y'}{xy}=0$$

$$x\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'+\frac{y'}y=\left(\frac{xy'}{y}\right)'=0$$

$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{c_1}{x}$$
$$\ln y=c_1\ln x+c_2$$
$$y=c_3x^{c_1}$$